# Insert if not exits oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to insert a record in a table only in case it does not exist.

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
 SELECT re.column1, re.column2, re.column3, re.column4
  FROM RECEPCION_ELEMENTOS re
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM table re2
                WHERE re.column1 = re2.column1
                  AND re.column2 = re2.column2
                  AND re.column3 = re2.column3
                  AND re.column4 = re2.column4);
```

Searching the internet, I have built this query but it does not work, I receive this error

```
Error SQL: ORA-00947: no hay suficientes valores
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
```

and this query the "VALUES" is missing. Is this correct?

some help?

Comment: The syntax looks right.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @tripossi well it expects `6` columns (values)  and your `select` returns only `4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to use the logic (with 6 columns in select). If fewer columns in select is used, it will throw an error

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
 SELECT re.column1, re.column2, re.column3, re.column4,re.column5,re.column6
  FROM RECEPCION_ELEMENTOS re
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM table re2
        WHERE re.column1 = re2.column1
         AND re.column2 = re2.column2
         AND re.column3 = re2.column3
         AND re.column4 = re2.column4);
```

Check out the demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ec9b36db802c7e2691b53edc994cbbb6

One other thing, hope you are not actually using “table” as your tablename (it’s a reserved keyword) so would recommend to use other name. In my demo, I have used “Tab” instead.

Answer (score 1):

The exists logic actually looks perfectly valid to me.  The problem is that your insert specifies 6 target columns, but your select only provides 4 columns.  Perhaps one of the following is what you intend to do here:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
SELECT re.column1, re.column2, re.column3, re.column4, re.column5, re.column6
FROM RECEPCION_ELEMENTOS re
```

*Or*

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT re.column1, re.column2, re.column3, re.column4
FROM RECEPCION_ELEMENTOS re
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the error for me but allow me a question, where are the data to be inserted being inserted?

Comment: Which version are you using, relative to the comment you left above?

Comment: @tripossi table called `table` maybe?